# jQuery multiple css values - problems with "float"

Tags: jquery, css

So, I'm defining some CSS values with jQuery. I'm defining multiple values like so:

```
$('#elementId').css({
    height  : '60px',
    width   : '268px',
    display : 'block',
    float   : 'left'
});
```

Note I'm also adjusting the 'float'. Although it does work, 'float' (obviously) is a datatype, and my editor identifies it a such. I was wondering if there's a more proper way to change the float CSS value, rather than using the reserved float datatype. I suppose this is kind of an OCD issue, but I like to do things right.

Thanks.

Comment: `float` is reserved in JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try wrapping it in inverted commas:

```
$('#elementId').css({
    'height': '70px',
    'width': '280px',
    'display': 'inline-block',
    'float': 'left',
});
```

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wgwbw/)

Comment: Ha, it actually occurred to me just after I posted this question. Free answer for you!

Comment: @g2avityhitz Why not using a class?

Comment: My client uses a site that provides 4 generic templates. I'm hacking up the existing DOM with an external script.